# Getting string from text box in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am new to xcode. I have one string variable and one text box. I want to get the strings from the text box to the string variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just get the text property of the text box (I assume you mean a UITextField).

```
NSString *myString = myTextField.text;
```

Comment: I'm surprisingly not a fan of dot notation within Objective-C. However, the following is equivalent aravindhanarvi: [myTextField getText]; (Should be at least)

Comment: Actually, `getText` is not valid.